# In the Hobbit 3, why didn't the orcs... [spoiler]

Tags: plot-explanation, the-hobbit, the-battle-of-the-five-armies

In the Hobbit 3 (Peter Jackson), why didn't the orcs  use the worms to burrow directly into the mountain, or burrow straight to the gold, bypassing the armies? Why didn't they use the worms to battle, like Dune?

Comment: Oh come on, you are going to mark this as a duplicate when `wyrm` is misspelled? And that question doesn't even ask why they didn't go straight into the mountain and straight to the gold.

Comment: *"you are going to mark this as a duplicate when wyrm is misspelled?"* - Uh, no, who said that? That other question seems to ask pretty much the exact same thing. You might want to clarify what distinguishes this questions from the other one and vote to reopen it. But digging to the gold or not, it's practically the same question *"why not make use of the worms?"*.